# Page Scope Variables Disappear

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Suppose I have the following asp.net page:

```
public partial class SamplePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int UserID;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnSearchUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       UserID = 5;
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(UserID.ToString());
    }
}
```

but UserID is always 0. How to achieve it to be 5 always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a Button's click causes a postback and data is always lost during postbacks as HTTP protocol is stateless.. So you'll have to store that UserID into a viewstate to maintain its value...and that's why we have State Mangement's concept in Asp.net.
However you can achieve it like this...

```
public partial class SamplePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int UserID;
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
 protected void btnSearchUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    UserID=5;
    ViewState["UserID"] = UserID;
 }
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(ViewState["UserID"]!=null)
    Response.Write(ViewState["UserID"].ToString());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To persists data between postbacks you need to place it into current control's view state:

```
private int UserID
{
    get
    {
        return this.ViewState["UserID"] as int? ?? -1; // if data is missing, default value -1 will be returned
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["UserID"] = value;
    }
}
```